# Is it appropriate to use continuous regression for dependent variable that consists of equidistant categorical responses?

Tags: regression, econometrics, survey, ordinal-data

I have survey data where the dependent (y) variable was collected as a percent value between 0% and 100% at 10% intervals. In other words, respondent could choose one of 0%, 10%, 20%, ..., 90%, 100%.

Typically, when working with ordered data such as Likert scale, the proper direction would be to use ordered regression methods. However, that feels inappropriate here given that ordered regressions would not account for the equidistant nature of this data.

Would treating y as continuous and using a continuous regression be the proper course of action here? Or is there some model type that specifically account for this type of data? I tried looking this up but came back empty handed.

Thank you!

Comment: Just because the *numbers* are equidistant does not imply they should be analyzed as equidistant. Your scale is no different than a 0, 1, ..., 10 scale. Thus, valid arguments can be made for both ordered regression and ordinary regression.  One way to investigate this question is to do both and compare the goodness of fit.  Another is to consider how respondents made their choices.  If they actually measured something, ordinary regression would be the place to start.  But it sounds like they are giving more subjective responses than that, suggesting caution.

Comment: Thank you @whuber, this makes a lot of sense. I'll do some experimenting. And you're correct, they're subjective responses. I appreciate your feedback on this.